# Recommended number of web applications on single server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i would like to know What is the Microsoft recommended number of web applications in one wfe server and what is the hardware requirement to achieve good performance to serve for all clients?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how many sites you are using, how many users do you have.

So there are many factors to check for better performance to server.

You can check the standard sharepoint capacity management links for better performance:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I am going to maintain the users in membership provide db. It is FBA site.Assume i am going to maintain average 100 users per site. One web application & one site per client. in the same way  how many web application & sites i can manage in the single server

Comment: You can check recommended sharepoint capacity management data for your needs. It also depends upon the configuration of your server and how much data are you going to store in your sites.